# Can Magic Jar posses zombie bodies?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, zombies

The *Animate Dead* spell and *Magic Jar* both need a "humanoid body" to target. Can I target a zombie with Magic Jar?

Or can I target only a non-zombie humanoid dead body with Magic Jar?

Answer (score 10):

No.

Animate Dead targets a dead humanoid body.  It turns that into an undead.

Magic Jar targets a (living) Humanoid, which is a defined 5e type. Zombies are not Humanoids (https://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/monsters-foes/monsters-by-type/humanoids/), they are Undead (https://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/monsters-foes/monsters-by-type/undead/).